# Standalone graphic has still borders left and right

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, border

I am working with small graphics which must not have any border. Surprisingly for me this code produces small (1-2mm) borders left and right. Could you enlighten me?

This code...

```latex
\documentclass[tikz=true,border=0pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]%
    \draw [line width=5mm, color=green] (0,0) -- +(5,0) {};
    \draw [line width=5mm, color=red] (5,0) -- +(5,0) {};
    \draw [line width=5mm, color=green] (10,0) -- +(5,0) {};
    \draw [line width=5mm, color=red] (15,0) -- +(5,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

..produces this output:

[image: left and right are white spaces]

Comment: I don't have an answer as to why you obtain the borders left and right. However, if you replace your draw commands by `\draw [fill = green, color = green] (0, 0) rectangle +(5, 5);` and giving them the right color and the right starting point, you get rid of the side borders.

Comment: Thanks @KersouMan. That works for me! Could you move your comment as an answer? I would accept that.

Comment: What you are seeing is the line caps. See my answer... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asked by the OP, here is a fix to get rid of the border lines that however does not tell why they were there in the first place:

```
\documentclass[tikz=true,border=0pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]%
    \draw [fill=green, color=green] (0,0) rectangle +(5,5);
    \draw [fill=red, color=red] (5,0) rectangle +(5,5);
    \draw [fill=green, color=green] (10,0) rectangle +(5,5);
    \draw [fill=red, color=red] (15,0) rectangle +(5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just use the command `\fill`:  `\fill[green] (0,0) rectangle +(5,5);`

Comment: You forget, that OP use `linewidth=5mm`. Using it your workaround gives strange result ...

Comment: @Zarko yes --- the "problem" here is line caps behavior.

Answer (score 8):

The lines normally are extended a bit to take into account the "caps" (see why in
 [Schrödinger's cat's answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513333/38080)).

You can see what's happening if you use:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm, line cap=round]%
```

and you'll obtain:

[image]

The manual explains this:

[image]

You can use `rect`, but the output is funny:

[image]

add transparency to see what's happening):

```latex
\documentclass[tikz=true,border=0pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm, line cap=rect]%
    \draw [line width=5mm, color=green, opacity=0.4] (0,0) -- +(5,0) {};
    \draw [line width=5mm, color=red, opacity=0.4] (5,0) -- +(5,0) {};
    \draw [line width=5mm, color=blue, opacity=0.4] (10,0) -- +(5,0) {};
    \draw [line width=5mm, color=yellow, opacity=0.4] (15,0) -- +(5,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is correct answer! +1