# drawing a line with varying colors

Tags: color, draw, line

My goal is to draw a line in different colors and not start a new line, so this produces a line and is working:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz=true,border=0pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]%
    \draw [line width=5mm, color=green] (0,0) -- +(5,0) {};
    \draw [line width=5mm, color=red] (5,0) -- +(5,0) {};
    \draw [line width=5mm, color=green] (10,0) -- +(5,0) {};
    \draw [line width=5mm, color=red] (15,0) -- +(5,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

It would be nice not to start a new line...like this:

```latex
...
    \draw [line width=5mm, color=green] (0,0) -- +(5,0) -- [color=red] - +(5,0) -- [color=blue] - +(5,0) {};
...
```

Cannot find an approach. It is just to ease things a bit.

Comment: According to [this webpage](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/contrib/tex-contrib/beamer/pgf-1.01/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-tex4ht/en/pgfmanualse9.html), you cannot change the color option along path, you have to split your path as you did in the first version of the code.

Comment: You could define a pic-style that is a line with varying colours, but behind the scenes it would still work using multiple paths.

Comment: All right - would be easier sometimes. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `postaction` with `dash pattern`.

```
\documentclass[tikz=true,border=0pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]%
    \draw [line width=5mm, color=red,postaction={draw=green,dash pattern=on
    5mm off 5mm}] (0,0) -- +(20,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

The white gaps at the end come from the requirement that the bounding box is also correct if you use `line cap=rect`. You need the larger bounding box if the path is not just a horizontal line since otherwise parts would get clipped away.

Comment: If you do not like these white gaps, use `\documentclass[tikz=true,border=0pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]%
 \clip (0,-2.5) rectangle ++ (20,5);
  \draw [line width=5mm, color=red,postaction={draw=green,dash pattern=on
    5mm off 5mm}] (0,0) -- +(20,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}`.

Comment: also a nice approach. thank you @Schrödinger's cat! This explains the gaps